# Can't move the image with collidepoint(event.pos)?

Tags: python, pygame

I've just recently become interested in **pygame** and the thing is my code doesn't work as what I intended: the image that I want to move with my mouse doesn't moving at all. So here's mine (contains code from previous question I saw):

```py
import pygame,sys,os

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GREY = (128,128,128)

class SilverGeneral:
    def __init__(self,rect):
        self.click = False
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    def update(self,screen):
        if self.click:
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode([1000,600])

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
silv = SilverGeneral((5,5,40,20))
silv.rect.center=screen.get_rect().center
clock = pygame.time.Clock()        
image = pygame.image.load("c:\game\silvergeneral.bmp").convert()

while 1:    
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            print(silv.rect.collidepoint(event.pos))
            if silv.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print("True")
                silv.click=True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print("False")
            silv.click=False
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    print (pygame.mouse.get_pos())
    print (silv.rect.center)
    silv.update(screen)        
    screen.blit(image,silv.rect)
    clock.tick(10)
    pygame.display.update()
```

I have been thinking for a whole hour and don't know why the `collidepoint(event.pos)` doesn't work. Also even if it's tested, the console never prints `True`.

Comment: *"my code doesn't work as what I intended"*. Why don't you tell us how the code is supposed to work and what you've tried to fix it? Please read the "how to ask" page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you skrx. Next time I will be more careful

Comment: You should improve this question now, because it's unclear and will be hard to understand and find for everybody with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collidepoint(event.pos)` works just fine.

It seems that you want to be able to move the image once you click on it.
I guess your problem is that you expect it to work with clicking anywhere on that image, but you actually check if the mouse position is in the top left 40x20 pixel box of the image.

You can easily verify that by changing

```
screen.blit(image,silv.rect)
```

to

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.color.THECOLORS['blue'], silv.rect, 0)
```

A good starting point is to use pygame's `Sprite` class and change your code to something like this:

```
class SilverGeneral(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, *groups)
        self.click = False
        self.image = pygame.image.load("image.jpg").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        if self.click:
            self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode([1000,600])

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
silv = SilverGeneral(sprites)
silv.rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while 1:    
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            silv.click = silv.rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and not silv.click
        elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    sprites.update()        
    sprites.draw(screen)
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

The important thing here is that the `rect` is set to the rect of the image, so it will have the right size.

---

[image]